# don't focus item on a gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I have a gridview when I am clicking one of the item it showing a blue box around this how to remove this

**without clicking looks like this**

[image]

**When clicking showing this kind of blue box**

[image]

how to remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `android:listSelector="#00000000"` to your gridview xml file. This will remove any kind of background of the gridview.